# Google drive using MacBook Pro and Vlware Fusion

Tags: windows-7

I am using a MacBook Pro. On this machine I also have Vlware Fusion with Windows 7 installed.
Do I install Google drive on the Windows side and also the MacBook side?

Comment: uh... install it on windows, then install it on osx?

Comment: They're different installations, so install the program on each one that you want to use it on.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive installs on both Macs and Windows PCs. You can essentially do it to both.

https://www.google.com/drive/download/

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the Google Drive Sync and Google Drive folder on the OS, you'll have to install Google Drive on each OS individually. If you install it only on the VM you'll only have the Google Drive Sync and the Google Drive folder on the Windows VM, but not the Mac and vice versa.

If you don't care about being able to access the Google Drive folder through Windows Explorer or Launchpad, you could go into a browser and sign into your Google account and access Google Drive that way.